# Python error : boolean index array should have 1 dimension

Tags: numpy

Here is what I'm trying to do

I have a matrix of data where rows represent different dates and columns represent the different stocks. The matrix is basically stock price data for certain number of stocks.

I have a vector x representing stock weights.

```
    array1 = np.array(closePrice[a,:])
    array2 = np.array(closePrice[b,:]) 
    select = ((array1 > array2))
    x[select] = x[select]+1  # This line gives error boolean index should have one dimension.
```

I don't get why select is not one dimensional boolean with length same as the number of columns.

Comment: Aside: if you're working with timeseries data, you're going to have a much easier time with [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) than with bare numpy.  With raw numpy you're going to spend most of your time reinventing wheels.

Comment: Make sure the shapes of `x` and `select` are the same?

Comment: @DSM : I  actually have no choice, I can only use Numpy and Scipy. I'm new to python and having a tough time.

Comment: @Divakar : x is a vector with length = number of stocks(say 10). array1 and array2 are also of the same shape: So shouldn't select be the same shape as x. Is there any way to ensure this ?

Comment: To make sure on that, you can actually print out the shapes with `x.shape` and `select.shape` and see if they match exactly?

Comment: `pandas` is a python package, very much like `scipy` and `numpy`

Comment: I'm coding into a terminal which doesn't accept print statement. The only libraries allowed are numpy and scipy. All I can is supply the x weight vector which is taken as a input by some background code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this thing worked, not quite sure why the previous didn't

```
array1 = array(closePrice[di-delay-Min,:])
array2 = array(closePrice[di-delay-Max,:])    
select[:] =  (array1[:] > array2[:])   
x[select[:]] = x[select[:]] + 1
```

Comment: You aren't giving us enough information to help you.  For example, you didn't specify how you initialized `select`.  For problems like this you need to understand and know the shapes of the various variables.  Otherwise it's just blind guess work.